# PHP POST request array not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

The following is on my controller, after using a POST command to extract data from a HTML form. The error says:

> undefined offset on the if statement concerning the $UserInput
>   variable.

It seems that the `$UserInput` is not an array. How do I access its contents using a for loop?

```
function proses_article_dutch(Request $request){

    $UserInput=$request->except('_token');
    $items=array('jongen','meisje');
    $answer=array('de','het');
    $result=array();

    for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
        if ($UserInput[$i]==$items[$i]){
            $result[$i]='benar';
            }
            else
            {
            $result[$i]='salah';
            }
    }
        return view('produk.articles_hasil',  ['hasil'=>$result ]);
}
```

Comment: The input should be an associated array. `Log::info($UserInput);` and you should be able to see what it contains.

Comment: Assuming you called the field on the form `name='fred'` then you would use `$UserInput['fred']`

Comment: I would suggest a `foreach` loop to process this rather than a `for`

Comment: You can`dump($UserInput);` and confirm the result has atleast 2 elements

Comment: @RiggsFolly foreach worked like a charm. Thanks for your help all